# SQL - What is best to do when multiple tables have the same columns

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I have different tables in my scheme with different columns, but I want to store data of when was the table modified or when was the data stored, so I added some columns to specify that.

I realized that I had to add the same "modification_date" and "modification_time" columns to all my tables, so I thought about making a new table called DATA_INFO so I won't need to do so, but every table has a different PRIMARY KEY and I don't know which one to add as FOREIGN KEY to the DATA_INFO table.

I don't know if I have to maybe add all of them or is there another way to do what I need.

Comment: Add a single column to all tables called `modification_datetime`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled And if you want (and if it is designed correctly), add a trigger to update this column with the current datetime on update. Or you will have to manually update this column in all of your adhoc code and sprocs.

Comment: @dfundako agreed.

Comment: In addition to the modification_datetime, you may also find a created_datetime to be useful.

Comment: Yes, that creation column was part of the idea too, thanks for your advises

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to have the same "modification_datetime" column in all tables, rather than trying to keep that data in a central table.

That's what we have done at every shop I've worked in.

Comment: How we did it in a healthcare environment, all tables had 4 audit columns: created datetime, created_by user, updated datetime, updated by user. Any time a record was updated, before the update, we inserted the record into a history table, updated the record in the non-history table, then updated the update audit columns. Just some anecdotal perspective if OP wants to go far on the auditing side.

Comment: I would not create audit table only for these four columns if we do not store actual data changes. Instead I would add such columns to the business tables as @TabAlleman mentioned

Comment: Thanks, I understood the reason why it cant happen. I'll stop being lazy and just type up the columns :D

Answer (score 0):

I want to emphasize that a separate table is not reasonable for this purpose.  The lack of an obvious foreign key is a hint.

Unlike Tab Allerman, tables that I create are much less likely to be updated, so I have three additional columns on most tables:

- `CreatedBy` -- the user who created the row
- `CreatedAt` -- when the row was creatd
- `CreatedOn` -- the system where the table was created

The most important point is that this information can -- in many databases -- be implemented using `default` values rather than triggers.  That is a big advantage of working within a single row.  The fewer triggers, the better.